# Rewrite custom url Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've this url in Wordpress:

```
http://mywebsite.com/examples/detail/?id=6341
```

I want to change this like that:

```
http://mywebsite.com/examples/detail/id/6341
```

So I wrote this into `functions.php`

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^examples/detail/?id=([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

But it does not work.

Comment: update permalinks ?

Comment: have you updated your permalinks ?

Comment: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules.Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.
So through this your changes will be affected.

Comment: Yes I did update them

Answer (score 0):

Try to update RegEx to catch what you want to see in URL and redirect accordingly:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^examples/detail/id/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Comment: It redirects me to the homepage

Comment: @CorentinBranquet so redirect worked, now just make correct target. Maybe not `index.php?id=$matches[1]`, but `examples/detail/?id=$matches[1]`...

Comment: Try this : add_rewrite_rule('^examples/detail/id/([0-9]+)/?', 'examples/detail/?id=$matches[1]', 'top');

But redirect to 404

Comment: @CorentinBranquet sorry, scratch that... target should start with `index.php?pagename=examples/detail&id=$matches[1]` (i'm not sure about `pagename=examples/detail`, it can be `p=??` where `??` is id of your page `examples/detail`)

Comment: The redirection is working for detail but it does not take the paramater id

Comment: Also /detail/ has a template page attached to it